# How to increase speed of count query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have about 10087250 records into users table, when i run count query

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users;
```

it is taking around 13 to 18 second. how can i reduce query time.

Comment: anyway, count can be slow. You can do estimated count, though, if it can suit your needs . https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/#distinct_counts_estimated

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : right (deleted my comment)

Comment: what's your server version?..

Comment: its postgres 9.6

Comment: hi Pac0 i go through with provided link, there i found this approach it is quite fast,      SELECT
  (reltuples/relpages) * (
    pg_relation_size('items') /
    (current_setting('block_size')::integer)
  )
  FROM pg_class where relname = 'items';      but won't work if record count when based on condition. Can you suggest something else?

Comment: Don't know Postgres but in MySQL there was very big difference between `SELECT (*) FROM table` for `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` storage for exactly the same table with 2M rows. In `MyISAM` the result was coming after e.g. 0.05 s and in `InnoDB` - e.g. 3 sec or even more. The difference was 100 times or more.